# Direcionar de uma view para outra utlizando ng-click no Ionic

Tags: ionic2, angular

Bom dia,

Gostaria de saber como faço para redirecionar essa view quando eu clico para ir para cada uma das opções do menu.

Notas Personalizadas
    
    
      
        {{nota.title}}

Comment: Opa, entendi sua duvida, mas para ficar mais fácil para explicar, poderia dar nome as views, tirar fotos ou algo assim? Assim fica mais simples para mim te explicar.

Comment: Acho que a resposta desse poste, pode lhe ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180590/como-adicionar-o-evento-click-em-um-componente-no-ionic2